# Serilization data format in a file

Tags: java, serialization

I am written some code for displaying the data some format  in a file

I am written below code:

```
File file=new File("D:/timesheet.txt");

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(timesheetlist.toString());

                bw.close();
```

My code is print the format like this:

[72013-02-0617:50:1519:19:15, 132013-02-0619:02:1119:02:25, 212013-02-0618:25:2218:25:22    , 282013-02-0618:25:4318:25:43, 442013-02-0619:20:2019:41:21, 562013-02-0617:54:0817:54:08  ]

But I want to display these format in file:

72013-02-0617:50:1519:19:15

132013-02-0619:02:1119:02:25

212013-02-0618:25:2218:25:22

282013-02-0618:25:4318:25:43

442013-02-0619:20:2019:41:21

562013-02-0617:54:0817:54:08

Here am using \n in class:

```
public class TimeSheetVO implements Serializable{


private String EMP_ID;
private String ATTENDANCE_DATE;
private Time IN_TIME;
private Time OUT_TIME;
private Time TOTAL_HOURS;

public String getEMP_ID() {
    return EMP_ID;
}
public void setEMP_ID(String eMP_ID) {
    EMP_ID = eMP_ID;
}

public String getATTENDANCE_DATE() {
    return ATTENDANCE_DATE;
}
public void setATTENDANCE_DATE(String aTTENDANCE_DATE) {
    ATTENDANCE_DATE = aTTENDANCE_DATE;
}
public Time getIN_TIME() {
    return IN_TIME;
}
public void setIN_TIME(Time iN_TIME) {
    IN_TIME = iN_TIME;
}
public Time getOUT_TIME() {
    return OUT_TIME;
}
public void setOUT_TIME(Time oUT_TIME) {
    OUT_TIME = oUT_TIME;
}
public Time getTOTAL_HOURS() {
    return TOTAL_HOURS;
}
public void setTOTAL_HOURS(Time tOTAL_HOURS) {
    TOTAL_HOURS = tOTAL_HOURS;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return EMP_ID + ATTENDANCE_DATE + IN_TIME + OUT_TIME + "\n";
}
```

}
Here \t is affect but not effect on \n
Am displaying arraylist object in file
Please give me any idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

`List.toString()` append open and close bracket `[..]`. Use `for-each` loop instead to write text,

```
   for(TimeSheetVO time: timesheetlist){
     bw.write(time);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but here space is coming line by line not displayed

Comment: Open the file with WordPad, Sometime Notepad can't display "\n" with newline.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (TimeSheetVO timeSheet : timesheetlist) {
    sb.append(timeSheet.toString());
    sb.append("\n");
}

File file = new File("D:/timesheet.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(sb.toString());
bw.close();
```

And remove "\n":

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return EMP_ID + ATTENDANCE_DATE + IN_TIME + OUT_TIME;
}
```